# How can I declare a global variable in Matlab for a few functions?

Tags: matlab, variables, global

I have a file called `histShape.m` with a function `histShape` , and some other functions also .

A general view of the code is :

```
%
function [outputImage] = histShape(srcimg, destimg)

    PIXELS = 255 + 1;

     ....
     ....
end



%
function [outputImage] = normalizeAndAccumulate(inputImage)

   PIXELS = 255 + 1;

....
....

end

%
function [pixels] = getNormalizedHistogram(histogram , inputImage)


   PIXELS = 255 + 1;

  ....
  ....

end
```

I can use `global x y z;`  but I'm looking for a different way .

I want to declare the variable `PIXELS` as global , how can I do that ?

Regards

Comment: Rather pass a scope variable as function parameters than using a global. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can gain access to a global variable inside a MATLAB function by using the keyword `global`:

```
function my_super_function(my_super_input)
    global globalvar;

    % ... use globalvar
end
```

You will usually declare the global variable in a script outside the function using the same keyword:

```
% My super script
global globalvar;
globalvar = 'I am awesome because I am global';
my_super_function(a_nonglobal_input);
```

However, this is not strictly necessary. As long as the name of the global variable is consistent between functions, you can share the same variable by simply defining `global globalvar;` in any function you write.

All you should need to do is define `global PIXELS;` at the beginning of each of your functions (before you assign a value to it).

See the official documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html).

Comment: Yeah , but the global variable is not shared with the other functions , that's the problem..

Comment: This solution is NOT (or no longer) the correct answer to the original answer.  The correct solution, i.e. **nested** functions, is given by @Stefan Karlsson.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to generally undesirable use of global variables is just to pass in your PIXELS variable to each function. If you have many then you could make a struct to hold them.

```
%
function [outputImage] = histShape(srcimg, destimg, PIXELS)

     ....
     ....
end



%
function [outputImage] = normalizeAndAccumulate(inputImage, PIXELS)

....
....

end

%
function [pixels] = getNormalizedHistogram(histogram , inputImage, PIXELS)

  ....
  ....

end
```

Or with a struct

```
    %In the main script calling the functions
    options.Pixels = 255 + 1

    function [outputImage] = histShape(srcimg, destimg, options)

         PIXELS = options.Pixels;
         ....
         ....
    end
    %etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

If the only reason for using globals in the question is related to the code posted, then the best solution is to use [nested functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html). All you have to do is move the first `end` of your example to the very bottom of the file and you are done.

```
function [outputImage] = histShape(srcimg, destimg)
 PIXELS = 255 + 1;

function [outputImage] = normalizeAndAccumulate(inputImage)
   PIXELS = 255 + 1;
end

function [pixels] = getNormalizedHistogram(histogram , inputImage)
   PIXELS = 255 + 1;
end
end
```

never use global variables if you can avoid it.